# Instanceof does not show compile error with interface, but with abstract class does

Tags: java, instanceof

I think the title is self explanatory. 
So suppose I have this code:

```
interface A { }

abstract class B { }

class C { }

C c = new C();

System.out.println(c instanceof A); //fine
System.out.println(c instanceof B); // compile error
```

In a comment from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897467/why-does-this-instanceof-code-work-and-does-not-cause-a-compile-time-error) I read this:

> The compiler can never know whether a given type doesn't implement an interface because a potential subclass could implement it.

So if for `interface` this works, why it should not work for an `abstract class` ? It also should be extended by some other class, as it can't exist by it's own. Can someone clarify this?

**Update**
Compile message:

> Error:(22, 28) java: incompatible types: C cannot be converted to B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple: C extends Object. No subclass of C could possible extend B. You can't add *another* base class, because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Whereas a subclass of C can very well implement that additional interface. 
But there is simply no way how a C object could also be a B instance.

So:

```
D extends C implements B // obviously all fine
```

whereas

```
D extends B extends C
```

is impossible. Because B is **already defined** to *not* extend anything but Object. Of course, the "trick" here is that both classes B, C are both known, and as said: C isn't extending B.

Comment: **Unless** `class C extends B`; in which case it's legal again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Which isn't the case for `class C` in the OP.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In the above code example, it doesn't. C is given!

Comment: Yeah, makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take for example

```
class D extends C implements A{}

C c = new D();
```

The compiler can immediately tell that `c` can never refer to an instance of `B` because if a class extends `C` it cannot extend `B` also. As the above example shows, the same cannot be said of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it's strictly impossible to create instances of an abstract class in java.
The operator instanceof is called from class Object and cannot be called if there is no instance of a class that revoked it (object).